# Selecting item from dropdown list in website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would like to ask how I could automatically select the item which contains EUR in the dropdown list using Selenium and Python. The reference to the website is here:

https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/historicalprices.

Need to type substring in the search field and the dropdown list appears.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import time
import glob
import os, fnmatch
import pandas as pd
import re, os.path
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
#from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
#from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

print("Starting stock script")
p="C:/Users/apskaita3/Finansų analizės ir valdymo sprendimai, UAB/Rokas Toomsalu - Power BI analitika/Integracijos/1_Public comapnies analytics/2. Nasdaq Helsinki/Nasdaq_historical_prices"


stock_list =[


    {"name": "Nordea Bank Ab", "csv_name": "C:/Users/apskaita3/Finansų analizės ir valdymo sprendimai, UAB/Rokas Toomsalu - Power BI analitika/Integracijos/1_Public comapnies analytics/Databasesets/Nasdaq_historical_prices/NDA-FI.csv"}


 ]



for i in stock_list:
    csv_name = i['csv_name']
    print(f"Starting iteration {i}")
    cname = i['name']

    #chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   
    #chromeOptions.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9230')
    
        
    #driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\apskaita3\Desktop\gec\geckodriver.exe',service_log_path=os.devnull)
    #driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/msedgedriver.exe")

    """
    edge_options = EdgeOptions()
    edge_options.use_chromium = True
    edge_options.add_argument('headless')
    edge_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
    edge_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    edge_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    """
    #driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/msedgedriver.exe",{"edge_options":"edge_options"})

    #driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/msedgedriver.exe",{"edge_options": edge_options})


    #driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/msedgedriver.exe", options=edge_options)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/Users/apskaita3/Documents/geckodriver.exe', service_log_path="C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/geckodriver.log")
    if cname=="TietoEVRY Oy":



        #driver = webdriver.Edge(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        #driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/apskaita3/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/historicalprices")
        driver.refresh()
        fromDate = driver.find_element_by_id("FromDate")
        fromDate.click()
        fromDate.clear()
        fromDate.send_keys("2006-01-01")
        time.sleep(4)
        inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("instSearchHistorical")
        inputElement.send_keys(cname)

        #driver.implicitly_wait(6)
        time.sleep(4)
        #s=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ul[3]/li[3]/a/div[3]")
        #s=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'EUR')]")
        #s=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'EUR')]")
        s=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[matches(.,'EUR', 'i')]")
        #element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Nordea Bank Abp (EUR)']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[1].click();", s)
        #.click()
        #inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.acSearchResult-fnm').click()


        new_csv1 = pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';')
        if ('sep='  in new_csv1.columns.tolist()):
            new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';',skiprows=1)
        else:
            new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=',')

        new_df1 = pd.concat([old_csv1, new_csv1]).reset_index(drop=True)
        #old_csv1=new_csv1
        new_df1.columns = old_csv1.columns
        new_df1['Trades']=new_df1['Trades'].replace(" ", "")
        new_df1=new_df1.sort_values('Date', ascending = False).drop_duplicates()
        if 'Unnamed: 11' in new_df1.columns.tolist():
            del new_df1['Unnamed: 11']
        else:
            pass
        new_df1.to_csv(csv_name,index = False)
        print(new_df1.duplicated())


        os.chdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads")
        for e in os.listdir():
          if "-2006-01-01" in e:
            os.remove(e)
          else:
            pass
                

        
        filenames.clear()
        time.sleep(3)        time.sleep(2)

        driver.find_element_by_id("showAdjusted").click()

                        
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.find_element_by_id("exportExcel").click()
        print(5)
        time.sleep(8)
        
        driver.close()

        time.sleep(3)
        print(5)

        #path = "C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/"
        accepted_extensions = ["csv"]
        filenames = [fn for fn in os.listdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/") if fn.split(".")[-1] in accepted_extensions]
        #filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime)
        #print(filenames)
        #filenames=re.search("2006",filenames) 
        #print(filenames)
         
        filenames = [s for s in filenames if "-2006-01-01" in s]

        print(os.listdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/"))
        
        print(filenames)
        a1=filenames[0]

        try:
            old_csv1 = pd.read_csv(f'C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads/{a1}',sep=';',skiprows=1)
        except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
          #old_csv14 = pd.DataFrame()
            old_csv1  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Opening price','High price','Low price','Closing price', 'Average price','Total volume','Turnover','Trades'])

        new_csv1 = pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';')
        if ('sep='  in new_csv1.columns.tolist()):
            new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=';',skiprows=1)
        else:
            new_csv1= pd.read_csv(csv_name,sep=',')

        new_df1 = pd.concat([old_csv1, new_csv1]).reset_index(drop=True)
        #old_csv1=new_csv1
        new_df1.columns = old_csv1.columns
        new_df1['Trades']=new_df1['Trades'].replace(" ", "")
        new_df1=new_df1.sort_values('Date', ascending = False).drop_duplicates()
        if 'Unnamed: 11' in new_df1.columns.tolist():
            del new_df1['Unnamed: 11']
        else:
            pass
        new_df1.to_csv(csv_name,index = False)
        print(new_df1.duplicated())


        os.chdir("C:/Users/apskaita3/Downloads")
        for e in os.listdir():
          if "-2006-01-01" in e:
            os.remove(e)
          else:
            pass
                

        
        filenames.clear()
        time.sleep(3)
```

[image]

Comment: what have you tried? ([so] is here to help you, not to do your work...)

Comment: I am using this xpath  s=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ul[3]/li[3]/a/div[3]"). But it selects defined but I need select item which contains EUR in substring of item.Example element <div class="acSearchResult-fnm floatLeft">Nordea Bank Abp (EUR)</div>

Comment: Edit your question and add your code trials. Do not share it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares/historicalprices")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "nordicSearchBox"))).send_keys("Nordea Bank Abp")
# Below line locates the desired element and stores in the variable
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Nordea Bank Abp (EUR)']")))
# Below 2 lines will click on the desired element
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Comment: Actually I need select that item which contains EUR substring in item name. nordea was just example. From dropdown list I need select just one element which contains EUR. That is the point.

Comment: I used this:     s=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'EUR')]"), but still it selects wrong item than I expected.

Comment: Change the XPath to: `//div[contains(text(),'EUR')]` and try.

Comment: I tried it still selects wrong item, it selects other than with EUR prefix. Actually selects first item.

Comment: Share your full code in the question. Do not just share one line of code.

Comment: Done. You could check it.

Comment: So how to solve this?

Comment: Shawn I didn't hear answer.

Comment: @Zymantas you might want to be a bit more polite to people trying to help you. "I didn't hear [your] answer" is *very* demanding and there's little evidence that you are entitled to such demands. keep in mind that we are all volunteers here...

Comment: I really stuck on this.